# Voice assistant using tkinter for interface

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

How to give interface to the voice assistant. When you start the program it opens one window there it run the voice assistant program .it shows image when voice recognising.when you close the window the program will should also stop .

the whole program i done in python.so i tried using tkinter.when i create window as function  and call it in main function the window only show but the voice assistant program not start working.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.